# Second order elliptic equation with nonlinearity depending on the gradient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let us consider the problem 
$$-\Delta u =f(x,u,\nabla u)\text{ in }\Omega$$
$$u=0 \text{ on }\partial\Omega,$$
where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth and bounded domain. I have seen at many places, where it is written that since the nonlinearity depends on the gradient therefore it is not variational. I understand that it is not variational because we cannot find a functional of which critical points are the solutions of the given problem but I am not able to justify this statement.

Comment: How do you define variational? It is variational in the sense: find $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - f(u,\nabla u)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$ for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: @grew by saying that problem is variational I mean that there exists a functional J on $H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that critical point of J are the solution to given problem. The fact is that no such functional exists, and I need the proof of this.

Comment: What I can offer is a suggestion how to proof that $v \mapsto \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - f(u, \nabla u) \, v \, \mathrm{d}x$ is not the derivative of any $J$, under some assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @gerw Thanks.  How to prove that the above map is not the derivative for any J. $f$ can be as regular as we want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for a proof. Some details are missing, but I am confident that these can be filled.

Let us assume that there is a functional $J : H_0^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $J$ is Fréchet-differentiable at $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ with
$$J'(u)\,v = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - f(u,\nabla u)\,v\,\mathrm{d}x$$
for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
If $f$ is regular enough, we might be able to show that $J'$ is also Fréchet-differentiable with
$$J''(u)(v,w) = \int_\Omega \nabla w \cdot \nabla v - \partial_1 f(u,\nabla u) \, v \, w  - \partial_2 f(u,\nabla u) \, v \, \nabla w \, \mathrm{d}x$$
for $v,w \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Here, $\partial_i f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. argument $i$.
Hence, $J$ is twice Fréchet-differentiable, which implies that the second derivative is symmetric w.r.t. $v$ and $w$. But, in general, the last term might not be symmetric (try integration by parts).